# Entity Print - Getting error while clicking on View PDF

Tags: entities

I am using Entity Print module and I didn't change its default configs.
[image]

I am using Dompdf library for generating PDF on node. I have enabled View PDF from Manage Display page. When I am clicking on View PDF to generate, I am getting this error:

```
Error generating document: Failed to generate PDF: file_get_contents(http://dots-eco-drupal.docker.amazee.io/sites/default/files/css/css_Hj6dvEdQZTchfggjPbCYnAxLsQNSftLPbmph0EKSGNo.css): Failed to open stream: Connection refused, Unable to load css file http://dots-eco-drupal.docker.amazee.io/sites/default/files/css/css_Hj6dvEdQZTchfggjPbCYnAxLsQNSftLPbmph0EKSGNo.css, 'box_sizing' is not a recognized CSS property., '_webkit_transition' is not a recognized CSS property., 'transition' is not a recognized CSS property., 'box_shadow' is not a recognized CSS property.
```

What I am missing on this? Please help me on this issue.

Comment: The listed error sounds pretty clear?

Comment: This question sounds like an exhaustively-discussed issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print/issues/2865185